# Creating a selector

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-selector

I want to create a selector in Android Studio. I created a file named "button_hover.xml" in folder res.layout.

**button_hover.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg1.png"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg2.png" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg3.png" />
</selector>
```

bg1.png, bg2.png, bg3.png is existed in my drawable folder, I can use Ctrl+Space to call them, but when I run the app, the console show the error:

```
Error:(5, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/bg1.png').
Error:(6, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/bg2.png').
Error:(7, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/bg3.png').
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: use `@drawable/bg1` instead, lose the `.png`

Comment: remove .png extension from where the drawable used

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check they are created under res/drawable, It seems they are under  from any of these folder:

```
/drawable-ldpi For low density screens.
/drawable-mdpi For medium density screens.
/drawable-hdpi For high resolution screens.
/drawable-xhdpi For extra high resolution screens.
```

If you are using android then select Project from just top of structure and you will see your draw-able are under which folder, they should be under draw-able if you are not using all sizes.

Answer (score 0):

selector XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/select_true" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/select_false" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_false" />
</selector>
```

select_true XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid
    android:color="#44ffffff"></solid>

<stroke android:color="#ffffff"
    android:width="1.2dp"/>

</shape>
```

select_false XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid
    android:color="#00ffffff"></solid>

<stroke android:color="#ffffff"
    android:width="1.3dp"/>

</shape>
```